# Cannot use a sensitive project parameter on SSIS 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, ssdt-bi

In SSIS 2012 I am trying to use a sensitive project parameter for an OLEDB connection for oracle.
It works perfectly with the Sensitive property set to `FALSE` (in Project Params Designer). But I do not want the password to be visible like that.
As soon as, I turn the Sensitive attribute to `TRUE` and try to execute my package, I get the following error:

> Error: 0xC0017010 at Package: The expression will not be evaluated because it contains sensitive parameter variable "$Project::OracleConnectionString". Verify that the expression is used properly and that it protects the sensitive information.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Vick

Comment: Try changing the package security protection level to **EncryptSensitiveWithPassword** and save the package and run.

Comment: How are you using $Project::OracleConnectionString? I *assume* that you are trying to assign it as an Expression on the Connection Manager, correct? If so, that's not the way to do with the 2012 Project Deployment Model

Comment: @RaoY Thanks for reply. At present the protection level is set to **DontSaveSensitive** and I am sticking with that unless there is a valid reason to change.

Comment: @billinkc Yes that's right, my solution is in Project Deployment Model and  I have parameterized the project connection for the connection string.

Comment: @billinkc what should be our approach for this in 2012 Project Deployment Model. Please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: @Vick are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: @billinkc, you said that assigning ConnectionString parameters to Connection Manager as expressions is not the way to do it in SSIS 2012. What's the recommended way then?

Vick, did you find an answer? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 3):

What I had to do was remove the password from the connection string, leave its Sensitive attribute set to False.  Then add an expression for the Password.  Set it and then set its Sensitive attribute to True.

Comment: This worked for me, even while deploying the package in SSIS server, through PowerShell script.